# R shiny radiogroup Button change color

Tags: r, shiny

I am using the library shinythemes https://rstudio.github.io/shinythemes/ but I would like to change the color of radiogroup buttons. How can I change the color?

```
               radioGroupButtons(
                 status = "primary ",
                 inputId = "indicadores_radiogroup",
                 choices = c("Casos" = "Confirmados", "Muertes"= "Muertes"),
                 
               ),
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are using the `shinyWidgets` package. You can set `status = "danger"` for a red color, or `status = "success"` for a green color. Check the ' radio Buttons' panel in http://shinyapps.dreamrs.fr/shinyWidgets/

```r
radioGroupButtons(
   inputId = "Id064",
   label = "Label",
   choices = c("A", 
    "B", "C", "D"),
   status = "danger"
)
```

The `status` parameter adds a class to your button. The example gives your button the class `btn-danger`. Check the css associated.

```css
.btn-danger {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #d9534f;
    border-color: #d43f3a;
}
```

You can use an arbitrary string to add a custom class, e.g. : with `status = 'myClass'`, buttons will have class `btn-myClass`. Then you will need to specify the css.

```css
.btn-myClass {
    background-color: #ff4500;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I am using shiny widgets but what If I want a specific color  "#FF4500", like this for example

Comment: check the edit. you can use `status` to generate a custom class for your button

Answer (score 2):

For your own specific color, you can try the following:

```
ui = fluidPage(
    radioGroupButtons(
      #status = "primary ",  ##  you can change status value to change to select few colors
      inputId = "indicadores_radiogroup",
      checkIcon = list(yes = icon("check")),
      choiceValues = c("Confirmados", "Muertes"), 
      choiceNames = c("Casos", "Muertes"),
      justified = TRUE, width = "300px"
    ),
    tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='indicadores_radiogroup'][value='Confirmados']\").parent().css('background-color', '#FF4500');"),
    tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='indicadores_radiogroup'][value='Muertes']\").parent().css('background-color', '#7EF373');"),

  )
  server = function(...) {}

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This works to change the colors of the individual buttons, but do you know how to then make it so that they darken slightly when selected? This is what it does by default, but it doesn't do it when you give custom values like is done here

Comment: Define a custom class as noted in the other answer.

Comment: that is not helpful. I have defined a custom class but that doesn't answer the question of how to make it so the classes refer to when the option is selected vs. not selected