# How to globally supply css to each radioGroupButtons widget in a shiny app

Tags: css, r, shiny, shinywidgets

I have this minimal example adapted from here [R shiny radiogroup Button change color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66481290/r-shiny-radiogroup-button-change-color/66481701#66481701):

```
library(shiny)

  ui = fluidPage(
    radioGroupButtons(
     # status = "primary ",  ##  you can change status value to change to select few colors
      inputId = "a",
      checkIcon = list(yes = icon("check")),
      choiceValues = 0:3,
      choiceNames = paste0(0:3),
      justified = TRUE, width = "300px"
    ),
    tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='a'][value=0]\").parent().css('background-color', '#7EF373');"),
    tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='a'][value=1]\").parent().css('background-color', '#E7E7E7');"),
    tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='a'][value=2]\").parent().css('background-color', '#EDB6B2');"),
    tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='a'][value=3]\").parent().css('background-color', '#DE6B63');"),
    
    radioGroupButtons(
      # status = "primary ",  ##  you can change status value to change to select few colors
      inputId = "b",
      checkIcon = list(yes = icon("check")),
      choiceValues = 0:3,
      choiceNames = paste0(0:3),
      justified = TRUE, width = "300px"
    ),
    tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='b'][value=0]\").parent().css('background-color', '#7EF373');"),
    tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='b'][value=1]\").parent().css('background-color', '#E7E7E7');"),
    tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='b'][value=2]\").parent().css('background-color', '#EDB6B2');"),
    tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='b'][value=3]\").parent().css('background-color', '#DE6B63');")
    )
  server = function(...) {}

  shinyApp(ui, server)
```

It basically colors the grouped radio buttons.

I would like to apply this colors to each radioGroupButtons Widget without using the four rows again and again.

I tried doing it with a css file in the parent directory but I don't know how to write the four rows in css e.g.

How to write:

```
 tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='a'][value=0]\").parent().css('background-color', '#7EF373');"),
    tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='a'][value=1]\").parent().css('background-color', '#E7E7E7');"),
    tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='a'][value=2]\").parent().css('background-color', '#EDB6B2');"),
    tags$script("$(\"input:radio[name='a'][value=3]\").parent().css('background-color', '#DE6B63');"),
```

in the .css file and use it in the radioGroupButtons widget?

Comment: This is not CSS, this is JavaScript. I think you can remove `[name=...]` to target the two groups with only one set of four rows.

Comment: As @StéphaneLaurent pointed out just use `tags$script("$(\"input:radio[value=0]\").parent().css('background-color', '#7EF373');")` etc.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent and ismirsehregal thank you both very much. I learn many thing by your post. However I am struggling on this <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74537975/how-to-store-a-shiny-reactive-data-frame-as-csv-on-hard-drive-locally-and-append> now since days. I simple want the user to be able to save the reactive dataframe into his harddrive (download it). Ideally next time if there is already a csv on this hard drive the new data will be appended. Quite lost many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tags$script` is used to run some JavaScript code, this is not some CSS code (`tags$style` is used for CSS).

The first part of this code:

```js
$(\"input:radio[name='a'][value=0]\").parent().css('background-color', '#7EF373');
```

i.e. `$(\"input:radio[name='a'][value=0]\")` selects one or more HTML elements. Namely, it targets all radio inputs with a `name` attribute equal to `'a'` and a value attribute equal to `0`. You can drop the part `[name='a']` so that the other radio group is selected.

If you want to put this code in an external file, create a `.js` file in the **www** subfolder containing this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio[value=0]").parent().css('background-color', '#7EF373');
  $("input:radio[value=1]").parent().css('background-color', '#E7E7E7');
  $("input:radio[value=2]").parent().css('background-color', '#EDB6B2');
  $("input:radio[value=3]").parent().css('background-color', '#DE6B63');
});
```

then include this file in your app by adding this code in the UI:

```r
tags$head(tags$script(src = "yourJSfile.js")),
```

See [here](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) for more information about selection by attribute value.

You could also proceed as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio").each(function() {
    var value = $(this).attr("value");
    var color;
    switch(value) {
      case 0:
        color = "#E7E7E7";
        break;
      case 1:
        color = "#EDB6B2";
        break;
      case 2:
        color = "#AAAAAA";
        break;
      case 3:
        color = "#DE6BB3";
    }
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', color);
  });
});
```

Or if you want to target only these two radio groups:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input:radio").each(function() {
    var name = $(this).attr("name");
    if(name === "a" || name === "b") {
      var value = $(this).attr("value");
      var color;
      switch(value) {
        ......
      }
      $(this).parent().css('background-color', color);
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Fantastic Stéphane  Laurent. Many thanks!!!